# SignalR and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, signalr

is there any way to use signalR on Visual Studio 2008. I don't have the visual studio 2012. So Thought to give it try on my 2008 version of visual studio.

Comment: Negative marker tell me how to install the library? why do you people mark negative .

Comment: Please [See this link][1] if it would be helpful:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068290/signalr-client-application-fails-to-connect-when-running-in-vs2008

Answer (score 4):

Nope, SignalR requires .NET 4.0 and above which requires vs >= 2010